# Magento 2 : Need to set custom category collection using plugin

Tags: magento2, category, collection

I want to set custom category collection using the plugin.

I created plugin about `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` this block and **aroundSetCollection()**. But, not actual output I received.

How to set custom collection using this plugin or is there any other way for that?